# Не могу получить список childNodes у body

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Изучаю реакт. Делаю простое приложение для администрирования страницы статического сайта. Суть в том, что на странице admin мы с помощью iframe загружаем главную страницу сайта и получаем все элементы страницы на которые вешаем обработчики для редактирования. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что получив iframe могу достучатся только к элементу body, но не ниже. Получаю iframe в нем есть #document, а внутри head и body и всё. Дальше пусто. childNodes у body нет, в тоже время если в консоли браузера попросить у iframe body childNodes все корректно отображается. Вот часть кода отвечающая за работу с childNodes, конкретно метод open().

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./../../helpers/iframeLoader.js";

export default class Editor extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.currentPage = "index.html";

    this.state = {
      pageList: [],
      newPageName: ""
    };
    this.createNewPage = this.createNewPage.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.init(this.currentPage);
  }

  init(page) {
    this.iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
    this.open(page);
    this.loadPageList();
  }

  open(page) {
    this.currentPage = `../${page}`;
    this.iframe.load(this.currentPage, () => {
      const body = this.iframe.contentDocument.body;
      console.log(body);
      console.log(this.iframe);

      body.childNodes.forEach(node => {
        console.log(node);
      });
    });
  }

  loadPageList() {
    axios.get("./api").then(res => this.setState({ pageList: res.data }));
  }

  createNewPage() {
    axios
      .post("./api/createNewPage.php", { name: this.state.newPageName })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.setState({ newPageName: "" });
        this.loadPageList();
      })
      .catch(() => alert("Такая страница уже существует"));
  }

  deletePage(page) {
    axios
      .post("./api/deletePage.php", { name: page })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.loadPageList();
      })
      .catch(() => alert("Что-то пошло не так"));
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <iframe src={this.currentPage} frameBorder="0"></iframe>
    );
  }
}
```

Вот загрузчик фрейма, но дело не в нем.

```js
HTMLIFrameElement.prototype.load = function(url, callback) {
  const iframe = this;

  try {
    iframe.src =
      url +
      "?rnd=" +
      Math.random()
        .toString()
        .substring(2);
  } catch (error) {
    if (!callback) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    } else {
      callback(error);
    }
  }

  const maxTime = 60000;
  const interval = 200;
  let timerCount = 0;

  if (!callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (!iframe) return clearInterval(timer);
        timerCount++;
        if (
          iframe.contentDocument &&
          iframe.contentDocument.readyState === "complete"
        ) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          resolve();
        } else if (timerCount * interval > maxTime) {
          reject(new Error("Iframe load file!"));
        }
      }, interval);
    });
  } else {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      if (!iframe) return clearInterval(timer);
      timerCount++;
      if (
        iframe.contentDocument &&
        iframe.contentDocument.readyState === "complete"
      ) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        callback();
      } else if (timerCount * interval > maxTime) {
        callback(new Error("Iframe load file!"));
      }
    }, interval);
  }
};
```

Весь код на гитхабе если нужно. https://github.com/Andykrvua/static_site_admin_panel

Comment: Проверьте, на этом этапе что-то есть? this.iframe = document.querySelector("iframe") ? а то выглядит так, что вы ищите на странице iframe, пока его там нет и весь дальнейший код рушится. И насколько я знаю, обращение в Реакте к DOM элементам напрямую - это плохо. Смысл Реакта в виртуальном DOM, состояниях и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, что присоединились.
this.iframe = document.querySelector("iframe") возвращает добавленный фрейм.
Случайно нашел в чем проблема. Оказывается все работает если не включать в консоли разработчика отключение кэша. И вот тут не понимаю, какая связь, почему так.